# How to use two different types of storage at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using latest vue2 and latest vue2-storage.

I'd like to have a local storage and session storage at the same time.
The goal is: store app config into local storage, store tmp user data in session storage.

As far as I get, the plugin will initialize only one storage for the whole app and - beside enforcing options each time you need it - there's no way to use a second storage on demand.

I've checked the source code and done some manual test but it seems impossible to import the constructor class to initialize a second storage.

Disclaimer 1: bare local/sessionStorage is not enough.

Disclaimer 2: I'm pretty new to vue2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi)) I have updated the package to version 6.0.0, which implements the ability to separately import the class and plugin. [issues/49](https://github.com/yarkovaleksei/vue2-storage/issues/49)

Answer (score 0):

Is it easier if you just use plain javascript ?
you can easily use `localStorage.setItem("test", "value")` and `localStorage.getItem("test")` , `sessionStorage.setItem("test", "value")` and `sessionStorage.getItem("test")`

Comment: no, or at least not for what you can get from vue2-storage. It takes care of de/serialize full objects, it has prefixes for storage keys, same interface for local/session/memory storage.
Of course, that's my fallback, but requires a lot of time/code.